# Why ForEach-Object doesn't work for AzureRM cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I am trying to execute a very simple cmdlet but it doesn't work

```
$resources = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | % { Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName}

$resources
```

The error message being thrown is as follows

> Get-AzureRmResource : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the
>   specified  named parameters. At line:1 char:45
>   + ... Group | % { Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupNa ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], Para     meterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.R
>   esourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ResourceGroupName` is part of a parameter set which means that if used it must be included along with the other mandatory parameters that belong to its set.

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652503.aspx) shows two parameter sets with that parameter is used.

```
#Parameter Set: Get resource by name and group
Get-AzureRmResource [-ApiVersion <System.String> ] [-ExpandProperties] [-ExtensionResourceName <System.String> ] [-ExtensionResourceType <System.String> ] [-IsCollection] [-ODataQuery <System.String> ] [-Pre] [-ResourceGroupName <System.String> ] [-ResourceName <System.String> ] [ <CommonParameters>]

#Parameter Set: Get resource by name, group and type
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <System.String> -ResourceName <System.String> -ResourceType <System.String> [-ApiVersion <System.String> ] [-ExpandProperties] [-ExtensionResourceName <System.String> ] [-ExtensionResourceType <System.String> ] [-ODataQuery <System.String> ] [-Pre] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Based on the parameters used in your script it cannot determine which set to use.

Either Add more parameters to your command to narrow down which set to use.

> Example 1: Get a resource
>
> This command gets a resource of the type microsoft.web/sites, named
>   ContosoWebsite under ResourceGroup11.
>
> Windows PowerShell

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "microsoft.web/sites" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -ResourceName "ContosoWebsite"
```

**OR**

use a set that takes parameters where the scope is narrower

For example:

`Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` returns an object like this

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmResourceGroup

ResourceGroupName : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Location          : xxxxxxxxxxxx
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              : 
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You could try passing the `ResourceId` to the next cmdlet.

```
#Parameter Set: Get a single resource by its Id.
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId <String> [-ApiVersion <System.String> ] [-ExpandProperties] [-ODataQuery <System.String> ] [-Pre] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

You command would then look like this:

```
$resources = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | % { Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceId $_.ResourceId}

$resources
```

Comment: $resources = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | Get-AzureRMResource this doesn't take pipeline input. Because as soon as you run it it throws errors for every single resource group and then Get-AzureRMResource just lists all the resources like it would on its own. This is a bug in this cmdlet in my opinion.

Comment: I said *IF* it takes piped input. check the documentation and the properties in the set do actually take piped input by property.

Comment: My issue is that the foreach cmdlet should work even if the cmdlet doesn't take any pipeline object. In the documentation `help get-azureRMresource` example 2 you can list all the resources by `Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceGroupName ContosoRG01` and they aren't providing any name or anything. Which tells me that documentation is wrong here.

Comment: I am using the online documentation. try updating your documentation `Update-Help` and see if you still get that example.

Comment: Use the resource Id

Comment: My goal was to find out resource groups with no resources in it. Overtime you have lot of resourcegroups with no resources in it and I want to delete those resource groups.

Comment: Then that should have been your original question. That is a good question. I would suggest either updating this question to reflect that or delete this one and ask what you really wanted.

Comment: I will post another question but I don't want to delete this communication as someone one might benefit or msft may notice.

Comment: I Understand what you mean. I guess it does explain why you got the error with the parameter sets.

Comment: Let me know when you have the new question. I have some ideas.

Comment: so I was able to accomplish that but I posted question to find a better way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452926/delete-azure-resource-groups-with-no-resources-in-it