# Unable to delete Azure Resource Group after deployment failure in it

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-group

I was deploying a set of resources in a resource group using Azure Managed Application on Service Catalog Managed Application which failed indeed due to some syntax errors (even though the syntax was correct and according to Azure Guidelines). Now when I open the failed resource, it displays nothing in it, which seems that there is nothing in the resource but just a reference to it. Later when I deleted the resource, it notified "cannot be deleted" or "successful deletion" however portal kept listing it in the resource group.

Secondly, when I tried to delete the resource group, it notified a deletion failure after a long interval, telling it was because of timeout.

I already gave a try to:

1. removing it using azure portal
2. removing it using powershell
3. azure cli
4. [azure resources](https://resources.azure.com/)

Question # 1: Is there any way to delete such resources or resource groups?

Question # 2: Is there any way to find out the failure reasons in details like in form of logs?

Comment: How long was this problem?

Comment: I am still facing this problem and it is here for more than weeks. @Sridharan

Answer (score 0):

Some Regions take more time to delete the resources.

For question 1 => You can try this solution if problem persists. [Delete Azure Resource Groups with no resources in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452926/delete-azure-resource-groups-with-no-resources-in-it?rq=1)

For question 2 => You can try this [Azure Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit)

Comment: They don't ask about region while deleting resources. My resource's region is west central us.

Comment: Edited the answer! 
 See if this helps https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/troubleshooting-cant-delete-azure-resource-group/

Comment: I am unable to remove resource group using the help from this link... ResourceGroupDeletionTimeout: Deletion of resource group 'ncclgroup03' did not finish
within the allowed time as resources with identifiers

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try logging into [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com/) to see if your resource group exists. If it does, you should be able to select your resource group, then select the "Delete resource group" option. If you can't delete it, or it doesn't exist it sounds like an issue that you may need to contact Azure customer support about. If you want to see what actions have been performed on the resource group, you can find a log of all high level Azure activity in the Azure [Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs).

Comment: This would be nice, but it costs $25 to even contact support now..

Comment: Wow sounds like friendly customer support... I haven't used assure since 2017, but I don't remember having to pay for support....